# Emulate Javascript 'alert' blocking nature

Tags: javascript, alert

Is it possible to create a custom modal message which 'blocks' the execution of the script until a user input?

For example, how can you achieve this without using the native window alert / prompt functions?

```
setInterval(function(){ 
     alert('Click OK to Continue');  // timing stops until user hits ok
},4000);
```

I know you could have your custom dialog invoke a callback function on user input, but I'm interested in being able to force this blocking behaviour

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  There's no way to add your own blocking methods, for security reasons.

Comment: @EliGassert "Unfortunately"? Odd choice of words ;-)

Comment: @pst unfortunately, because it'd make life easier for webdevs to make "pretty" blocking dialogs.  But I guess it is fortunate because it would be very easy to misuse :)

Comment: What's your issue with callbacks?

Comment: @EliGassert "Pretty blocking dialogs" already exist. "Having" to use asynchronous events *makes life easier* because then there are no concerns for standard threading race-conditions - yay! Most mainstream UI's use callbacks or message queues (excluding their respective "dialog/message box" implementations) even on thread-supporting environments.

Comment: @Christophe absolutely no issue with callbacks, only curious as I inherited code which has several native alerts/prompts and was looking into the least obtrusive way to replace them with custom dialogs

Comment: @pst Well... actually there isn't anything that blocks quite as strongly as a native popup. You can always Firebug (or your developer tools of choice) your way out of the others, if you're *really* intent on it.

Comment: @lostsource It's a good thing it's trivial to convert sequential code to poor-man continuations (once again, hurrah for no threads) ..

Comment: @pst no, pretty blocking dialogs do not exist.  By using async, it is, by definition, NOT BLOCKING.  It may visually block, but it is not blocking.  Execution continues on in the BG.

Comment: @EliGassert Naturally, "blocking *user* interaction" (was it *really* that hard to infer such?) ..

Comment: @pst apparently it is for you.  His question has nothing to do with "blocking user interaction" as it has to do with *real* blocking.

Comment: @EliGassert I tire of this. My previous comments show that I am well aware of the differences.

Comment: async/await can do it. Just return a promise. Not supported by all browsers yet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a custom modal message which 'blocks' the execution of the script until a user input?

No. There is no way to block either execution or user interaction as effectively as a native popup (since with custom popups the user is always technically capable of using developer tools to get out of it).

However, as pst says in the comments on the question, asynchronous lightboxes are not onerous, and are *almost* as effective at blocking user interaction as popups, so I recommend finding a library that provides lightboxes you like and running with that.

> For example, how can you achieve this without using the native window alert / prompt functions?

You can't use that code to do what you say it will even *with* native window alert / prompt functions (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MixolydianV/bstxt/) - wait 4 seconds before closing popup). You'd need the following:

```
function timeoutFunction() {
    alert('Click OK to Continue');  // timing ACTUALLY stops until user hits ok
    setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 4000);
}
setTimeout(timeoutFunction,4000);
```

Which is something that you can't implement (precisely - see above on lightboxes) without native popups.

Even `while(true)` loops won't generally block as well as a popup - firefox at least has a "stop script" message that pops up after it's been going too long, and I'm fairly sure other major browsers do too.

Comment: Well, what if one needs to override javascript assync functions? (e.g. userscript)

Comment: Imagine you had to override `alert` with custom blocking function, eg. an ajax call or something similary insane. If your life depended on it, how would you do it?

Comment: @TomášZato I wouldn't - `alert` is part of the language, which is built into browsers, so... No. Game over.

Comment: Well, you can override it, however you cannot replicate the blocking behavior. At least I don't know how - and that was my question.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't (at least not in a browser). Javascript APIs are mostly async. `alert`/`prompt` are exceptions. However, it's not very hard to work with async prompts and callbacks.

Comment: This is misleading. It implies that "everything except alert" is async, which is false. Of course, `while(true) { 1; }` is only so (i.e. not very) fun and yields an unresponsive page ..

Comment: `while(true)` isn't and API, it's a language construct!

Comment: So pick your "Javascript API". Say, `getElementById`. It's *not* asynchronous.

Comment: (I didn't down-vote, but this answer could be made to tie into the original question better.)

Answer (score -3):

A bit old, but in case it helps, I've found my solution with this:

`var answer = confirm("are you sure?");
 if(!answer)return;`