# personalized javascript dialog box?

Tags: javascript, dialog

I want to personalize (design css, buttons...) a "confirm" javascript dialog box but want to keep it's persistence. The dialog box shows after a countdown, so it's very important that it get focused even if the user is runing another tab of the browser or runing another application...

I found many beautiful solutions in the web but all of them neglect this aspect of persistence.

Regards

Comment: The short answer AFAIK is that it isn't possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emulate Javascript 'alert' blocking nature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635297/emulate-javascript-alert-blocking-nature)

Comment: And if this is possible, people will be EASILY annoyed by countless ad/spam...

Answer (score 0):

By persistence I am  not sure exactly what you mean. If your looking for a solution whereby the dialog prevents the user even being able to close the tab unless they supply data, it's not possible.

However I have recently developed my own dialog box. Extremely easy to style with css, check out the demo at the bottom and also the website http://dialogjs.com/

Before actually publishing your website I must ask you ensure it runs smoothly  as it is not 100% bug free. Also watch the space there are likely to be major changes as it's only a test release.

now for a confirm dialog you would simply

```
new Dialog()
.confirm("Continue?", function(result){
    this.data.continue = result;
})
.confirm(function(){return "Are you sure you wish to "+ (this.data.continue ? "continue" : "cancel")}, function(result){
})
```

You can also write your own dialog type http://jsfiddle.net/q5zL7y6e/1/

Answer (score 0):

**//HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <dialog id="dialog">
      <h4 id="dialog_header">Datenschutzhinweis</h4>
      <p id="dialog_text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
      </p>
      <label
        ><input
          type="checkbox"
          id="dialog_checkbox"
          value="checked"
        />Einverstanden</label
      >
      <button onclick="Dialog_close()">Dialog schließen</button>
    </dialog>

    <script src="dialogJS.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**//JS Code**

```
function Dialog_close() {
  var dialog_checkbox = document.getElementById("dialog_checkbox");
  var dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
  var dialog_text = document.getElementById("dialog_text");
  if (dialog_checkbox.checked) {
    dialog.close();
  } else {
    dialog_text.style.color = "red";
  }
}

document.getElementById("dialog").showModal();
```