# Pause function execution until another function returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am wanting to replace Magento's implementation of the alert() and confirm() dialog boxes. While the alert() replacement was trivial, I am unsure of how to handle the confirm() dialog. Is there a way to prevent JavaScript from continuing until a function is returned? Will this require looping that could crash a browser?

So for example, I need to replace code like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" value="Delete">
</form>
```

with...

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="submit" onclick="return myCustomConfirm('Are you sure?');" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Or other scenarios such as:

```
<script>
   var delete = confirm('Are you sure?');
   if (delete) {
       doSomething();
   }
</script>
```

with...

```
<script>
   var delete = myCustomConfirm('Are you sure?');
   if (delete) {
       doSomething();
   }
</script>
```

In both scenarios, myCustomConfirm() will open a Bootstrap modal where the user must click "Okay", "Cancel", or close the modal. The value returns true if "Okay" and false if otherwise.

I don't want to do callbacks as that will cause more refactoring than desirable. Is this possible to do in another way?

Thanks!

Comment: `delete` is [an operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) so don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: No, there is no way. You need to use callbacks for asynchronous code, you cannot avoid this. You might minimize refactoring by [using promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks/22562045), but any control structures do need refactoring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible. You cannot write a JavaScript function that blocks execution, gathers user input and returns a value based on user input. The only way to block execution and wait for user input is to use `confirm`.

You have to refactor your code to use callbacks if you want to use custom dialogs.

See [Emulate Javascript 'alert' blocking nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635297/emulate-javascript-alert-blocking-nature)

Comment: for the sake of completeness, `alert` and `prompt` also "blocks execution", although they are indeed simply variations of `confirm`

Answer (score 3):

You can do something similar to this using async/await which is part of ES7.

```
async function stepTwo()
{
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
  {
    let stop = false;
    $('input[type=checkbox]').one('change', (event) =>
    {
      // Will only stop the loop when the checkbox is checked
      if (event.target.checked === true)
      {
        stop = true;
      }
    });
    loop();

    // Continues looping until stop is set to true (i.e. input has been done)
    function loop()
    {
      if (stop === true)
      {
        resolve();
        return;
      }

      // Keeps checking if stop is true
      setTimeout(loop, 100);
    }
  });
}

async function stepOne()
{
  $('div').text('Waiting for input..');
  // Waits for promise returned from stepTwo() to resolve
  await stepTwo();
  $('div').text('Input checked!');
}

// Starts the async function (any lines below this continue execution)
stepOne();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1rvn5bfp/7/

Answer (score 0):

Just make your button open up the Bootstrap modal and add an event listener to the Okay and Close buttons

```
    <!-- Simple popup sample from Bootstrap.com: Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="hide_popup">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_stuff">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#save_stuff").on("click", function(){
    alert("This does something");
});
```

http://www.bootply.com/4Uflj4hKaL

Comment: The OP said they didn't want to use callbacks?