# How to get a bootstrap styled BLOCKING prompt

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, prompt, bootbox

Is there any way to get a bootstrap styled BLOCKING prompt so that you have to wait for the user to input a value before the code proceeds? I'm currently using bootbox but it uses a callback function which isn't helpful.

Comment: You can use a simple prompt function.

Comment: Reproducing blocking is impossible. See more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635297/emulate-javascript-alert-blocking-nature