# Custom alert/popup window and holding JS engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, popup

I want to design a custom alert/popup window to give the desired look and feel. I tried dialog example from [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup/#&ui-state=dialog). Now, I want that after the custom popup is shown, my JS engine should not proceed further until I take some action on popup. This is much like build alert/confirm popups available with JS.

In my example, `alert('2')` is getting executed as soon popup has rendered. I want that `alert('2')` should only be executed after I have clicked on "Cancel" or "Delete" on popup and the JS code associated with them is executed.

I know this is possible because [DHTMLX](http://dhtmlx.com/) framework has done it, it provides custom popup and until you do some action on that popup, next JS code will not execute.

Below is the minimum reproducible example.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

        <script>
           function testPopup(){
                alert('1');
                $("#popupDialog").popup("open");
                alert('2');
           }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="button" onclick="testPopup()" value="testPopup"/>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Delete Page?</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
    <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not possible with JavaScript.

Comment: Can you get a working jsfiddle of your problem? I might have an idea to help, thanks.

Comment: Also when should the alert('2') be called? After you do something with the pop-up?

Comment: @Chris I hv given the complete working example, you can test in your local box itself or if you wish then can it in jsfiddle .. Yes, `alert('2')` should be called after user has taken some action on popup ..

Comment: @epascarello There should be some way because DHTMLX has thing .. They must have done some workaround to achieve this ..

Comment: @pjj Lets see an example of that, do you have one that shows that feature working as you describe.

Comment: @epascarello I am afraid I cannot provide you a working demo but check this - http://docs.dhtmlx.com/message__windows_description.html .. I know it works with DHTMLX because we are using the licensed version in some other project .. Now, since are we are using open source jQuery mobile in our current project so I am looking for similar implementations ..

Comment: `callback: function() {dhtmlx.confirm("Test confirm");}` <-- It is not pausing! It is using a callback.

Comment: @epascarello Check the `dhtmlx.alert("someText");`

Comment: @hagrawal I know, but what OP says is that when `dhtmlx.alert("someText"); alert("I should not see this, but I do");` runs, the alert does not happen until you hit the okay button. That is totally wrong, it uses callbacks which OP says they do not want to do.

Comment: @epascarello To me, from the alert example it looks tht dhtmlx provides such functionality because their alert is not registering any callback, however I cannot be sure because I have not used this framework ..

Comment: It has a callback option.....

Comment: @epascarello I have been using it my project without any callback function, and when I say `dhx.alert("Service unavailable")` then a custom popup comes up, and until I click on OK button, JS engine will not proceed, and all this without me passing any callback to alert code. So, I am pretty sure that this is possible and available in DHTMLX, but not sure how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the popup widgets **[afterclose](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#event-afterclose)** event to fire the code that should run after the popup is dismissed:

```
function testPopup(){
  alert('1');
  $("#popupDialog").popup("open").on( "popupafterclose", function( event, ui ) {
    alert('2');
  });
}
```

## **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/z1shc0k8/)**

Comment: Thanks, nice suggestion, it is much like callback function, I know about it but I cannot do that because of many reasons and top most that I hv lot of coding done where I am using JS's build in `alert` and now I want to show a custom alert, if I hv to do your way then I hv to touch a lot of code .. I hv to find out a way where I can just replace `alert` with my code to show the custom popup and I can be sure that until user has taken some action on popup, nothing further will be executed ..

Comment: @pjj: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635297/emulate-javascript-alert-blocking-nature

Answer (score 1):

can suggest you to use sweet alert the are really easy to use and kind of fabulous in front end made a look :

1 ) download the sweet Alert zip and extract it .

2 ) check the dist folder and move the .min.js and the css file to your project . 
3 ) use them as defineed in the documentation [here](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

4) for you example it will be kind of

```
        <script>
          $("#popupDialog").click(function(){
             swal("congrats your popup work fine ");
          })
        </script>
```

hope it helped a little bit

NB : dont forget to load the css file first and the the JS file